# Mysql joining two tables associated via third table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table which are associated via third table . Third table has ids of the first two tables and the association value .
Structure and fiddle can be found here .

[**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/338027/2)

What I want to do is to get the row with all session and attributes .
So expected result is

```
+-------+-----------+-------+
| name  | attr_name | value |  
+-------+-----------+-------+
| sessA | attrA     | 9     | 
| sessA | attrB     | 5     |  
| sessA | attrC     | null  |  
| sessB | attrA     | null  |  
| sessB | attrB     | 1     |  
| sessB | attrC     | 1     |  
| sessC | attrA     | 1     |  
| sessC | attrB     | null  |  
| sessC | attrC     | null  |  
+-------+-----------+-------+
```

But I am getting only matched row .What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `cartesian product` between your attribute table and your session table.  To do this, you can use a `CROSS JOIN`.  Then you need to include the attr_id field in your join to the final table to get `NULL` values:

```
SELECT a.name, b.attr_name , c.value
FROM tbla a CROSS JOIN tblB b
    LEFT JOIN tblc c ON a.sess_id = c.sess_id 
        AND b.attr_id = c.attr_id
ORDER BY a.name, b.attr_name
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/338027/14)